# UIView's snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:, determine if afterScreenUpdates needs to be YES

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

If you call *[view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO]* on a view that hasn't been displayed yet, you get:

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

This goes away by changing the param to YES, which makes sense. Passing YES has a performance hit, and I don't need "after screen updates" unless it hasn't been displayed yet. Is there a way to know when passing in NO will cause that error, so that I can pass in YES only in that scenario?

I tried *[view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:view.layer.needsDisplay]*, but that didn't do it.

Comment: Your best bet might be to use a `UIViewController` for said view. You would use `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` in that case. If not, you could use a delegate method of the view like `willMoveToSuperview` or something. And then use the snapshot API in the respective method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `UIView` exposes whether or not it has unrendered changes. I usually only pass `NO` when I know (based on context) that the view has already been displayed, such as when creating a snapshot for a view that is about to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `YES` to cater for cases like, when your view has not completed its animations or finished rendering the changes (set new background color) and user has performed some action which invokes snapshot. If you are sure that your snapshot method will be invoked when your view has finished rendering OR that you can afford to snapshot un-finished rendered view then you can set it to `NO`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with TextFiled with widhtAnchor & heightAnchor to setup that on my view. The Snapshot error has gone...

On Swift 5 I put this:

```
private func setupUI() {
    view.setNeedsDisplay()
    view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

...

Comment: Where exactly? viewDidLoad?

Comment: On my case, I insert on viewDidLoad.